# Сортировка в GridView по динамическому полю

Tags: php, yii2

1. Есть таблица, в ней 3 поля (`id`,`name`,`date`)
2. Есть модель TableModel.php сгенерированa с помощью Gii
3. В TestModel.php есть динамическое поле

```
 public function getParam(){
     return rand();
 }
```

Теперь модель имеет не 3 свойства a 4

```
$model->id;
$model->name;
$model->date;
+
$model->param; // динамическое поле
```

4. Есть вид с GridView и сортировкой по 3-м полям (`id`,`name`,`date`)
   Как добавить в GridView сортировку по 4-му `param` полю?

Comment: В модель, где три поля, добавить свойство public $param;

Comment: @fedornabilkin спасибо за ответ. Параметр у меня установлен. У меня нету ворнингов или ошибок, меня интересует именно шаги добавления столбца в GridView и, соответственно в TableModelSearch.php

Answer (score 1):

В `GridView` параметр поля:

```
['param'],
```

В моделе поиска:

```
// add conditions that should always apply here
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
   'query' => $query,
]);
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['param'] = [
   'asc' => ['param' => SORT_ASC],
   'desc' => ['param' => SORT_DESC],
];
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Сейчас база ругается на отсутствие поля "param"

Comment: ‘public $param;’ добавте